# C# how to stop topshelf service from masstransit fault consumer

Tags: c#-4.0, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am running a Masstransit (using rabbitMQ) within a Topshelf Windows Service. How can i force stop the topshelf service whenever there is exception in consumer ie. from the FaultConsumer?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hang on to the `HostControl` argument that is passed to the `Start()` method of the `ServiceControl` interface. If at any time you need to request the service be stopped, call the `Stop()` method.

```
public interface ServiceControl
{
    bool Start(HostControl hostControl);
    bool Stop(HostControl hostControl);
}

public interface HostControl
{
    void RequestAdditionalTime(TimeSpan timeRemaining);

    void Stop();

    void Restart();
}
```